# Dagger 2.0 - AppEngine - gradle configuration

Tags: java, google-app-engine, gradle, dagger-2

I am trying to move from Dagger 1.2.2 to Dagger 2.0.1 in AppEngine project (**NOT** Android one).

With Dagger 1.2.2 simple:

```
compile 'com.squareup.dagger:dagger-compiler:1.2.2'
compile 'com.squareup.dagger:dagger:1.2.2'
```

did the trick.

With Dagger 2.0.1:

```
compile 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.0.1'
compile 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.0.1'
```

does not work (source is generated but mixed up with *.class files in build/classes/main/..package../).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a solution.

https://github.com/tbroyer/gradle-apt-plugin

```
buildscript {
  repositories {
    maven {
      url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/"
    }
  }
  dependencies {
    classpath "net.ltgt.gradle:gradle-apt-plugin:0.3"
  }
}

apply plugin: "net.ltgt.apt"

dependecies {
  apt 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.0.1'
  compile 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.0.1'
}
```

Additionally if you are using Intellij a following configuration is recommended:

> When using the Gradle integration in IntelliJ IDEA however, rather
>   than the idea task, you'll have to manually enable annotation
>   processing: in Settings… → Build, Execution, Deployment → Compiler →
>   Annotation Processors, check Enable annotation processing and Obtain
>   processors from project classpath. To mimic the Gradle behavior and
>   generated files behavior, you can configure the production and test
>   sources directories to build/generated/source/apt/main and
>   build/generated/source/apt/test respectively and choose to Store
>   generated sources relative to: Module content root.

I've also had to remove Exclude from whole build directory and mark generated/source/apt/main directory as source.

Answer (score 2):

You can also do it without `net.ltgt.apt` plugin, (which by the way may conflict with lombok).

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'idea'

def generatedMain = new File(buildDir, "generated/main")

compileJava {
    doFirst {
        generatedMain.mkdirs()
    }
    options.compilerArgs += ['-s', generatedMain]
}
idea.module.sourceDirs += generatedMain

dependencies {
    compileOnly 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.8'
    compile 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.8'
}
```